# Microsoft Graph API - how to get access token without Authorization Code?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want my Web API to get an Access Token to then call Microsoft Graph API. I've gone through a few documents and threads but they all talk about a POST method that asks for a Client ID and App Secret created when registering the app on AAD.

I'm following this document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#service-to-service-access-token-request).

My problem is:

What is `client_credentials`? Where should I get it from? I thought the API is supposed to be working with the secret and the client I'd only.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's 4 parameters in the HTTP request:

1. grant_type: in this case, the value is "client_credentials"
2. client_id: The client id of your app
3. client_secret: The client secret of your app
4. resource: The identifier of the API you want a token for, in this case `https://graph.microsoft.com`

So only client id and secret are needed from your app.

If you use v2 endpoint / MSAL, note there is no resource parameter.
Instead you would use `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer - the value to grant_type was really misleading me. although now I'm receiving a bad request where it complains about `grant_type` with this message `The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type' ` I think I have a valid request here for this endpoint: 

`$"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token"`

`{
 "grant_type":"client_credentials",
 "client_id":"<client_id>",
 "client_secret":"<secret>",
 "scope":"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}`

Comment: It needs to be sent as form data :) Not as JSON. Check the example request in the documentation link you posted.

Comment: There is an example here at least (the second one using FormUrlEncodedContent) http://ronaldrosiernet.azurewebsites.net/Blog/2013/12/07/posting_urlencoded_key_values_with_httpclient

Comment: omg - absolutely right  - in front of my eyes! Thanks - you helped so much :)

Comment: @juunas thanks a million (I was sending it as JSON for half an hour)